# How to use a dynamic variable in runtime in Apache Beam / DataFlow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have created a custom template for Apache Beam / DataFlow but I want a timestamp variable to be dynamic. What is the correct way to dynamically retrieve the timestamp in Apache Beam?

```py
    def run():
        #...
        time_format_exp = "%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00 UTC"
        now_time = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
        #...
    
        with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
            
            _ = (
                    pipeline |
                    #... using now_time dynamic variable
            )
```

Comment: I don’t correctly understood the need. You want to retrieve the current timestamp directly in the pipeline or pass it in a program argument for the job ?

Comment: I want to retrieve the timestamp dynamically at runtime. The idea is for the date to be dynamic.

Comment: Did you try to use ParDo() function? https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/elementwise/pardo/#example-2-pardo-with-timestamp-and-window-information

Comment: Hi @RafaelChristófano, no I want to create a template for a dynamic query on BigQuery. Each time the pipeline runs, the query should be different. However, since this gets serialized, it is always the same query.

Answer (score 0):

I hope to understood correctly your need.

You can pass you `now_time` parameter in a function as follow :

```py
def test_pipeline_timestamp(self):
        with TestPipeline() as p:
            time_format_exp = "%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00 UTC"
            now_time = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
            
            # Pass the now time in the function invoked in a lambda expression.
            _ = (
                    p | beam.Map(lambda el: self.transformation(el, now_time))
            )

            # Pass a function and the now time as a parameter.
            _ = (
                    p | beam.Map(lambda el: self.transformation, now_time=now_time)
            )

    def transformation(self, element, now_time):
        return element
```

- You can use a lambda expression in the `beam.Map` transformation and pass your param inside the function.
- You can use the function directly in the `beam.Map` and use a parameter to pass extra elements

Comment: I am using `now_time` to build a query but since the template gets compiled the query is not dynamic.